# forcing a trailing slash at the end of site_url()

Tags: php, wordpress, url

I have a wordpress website with a banner link showing as below:

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>" >Banner</a>
```

And this will return a result as: http://example.com

What I want is to let the site_url have a trailing slash, so the address would look like http://example.com/

So my question, is it okay to concatenate the site_url() with a trailing slash like this?

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url() . '/'; ?>" >Banner</a>
```

Comment: Probably the worst it could do is lead to some concatenated paths being output with a double slash after the domain. This *shouldn't* cause any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you are did is Ok. But I have a little different solution weather it contains trailing slash or not just add it like this.

```
$url = site_url();
echo rtrim($url ,"/").'/';
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer works, but if you want a full WP solution, use [`trailingslashit()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/trailingslashit/):

`$url = trailingslashit( site_url() );`